# Find root with chord method

Tags: interpolation

With chord method find real root of the equation

$x^3 - 2x+1-{e^x\over2} = 0$  accurate to $0.001$

I can not perform first condition in the method of chords

Comment: @Moo No, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chord (or secant,
as I understand it) method:

To approximate a root of
$f(x) = 0$,
from two points
$(x_1, f(x_1)$,
$(x_2, f(x_2)$,
make the line through
these two points
$L:
\frac{y-f(x_1)}{x-x_1}
=\frac{y-f(x_2)}{x-x_2}
$.

Then,
solve for the
$x$ that makes
$y = 0$.

This is the 
next $x$;
call it $x_3$.

Continue with
$x_2$ and $x_3$
and so on
until $y$ is sufficiently small.

Is there anything that
you do not understand?